# Change naming of sections in Craft Commerce CMS

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, language, products

Is it possible to change the name of the of 'Products' to 'Projects' & Variants to 'Pledges'? I would like to use the Commerce CMS as a base to start from but need to be able to change certain naming of sections. Where can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a custom translations file for Commerce and override some of the default translation strings.

1. Go to vendor/commerce/translation/[your-language].php
2. Review the instances of the word you want to translate (could be a lot)
3. In your project root, create a directory called `translations`
4. Inside of this directory create a directory with your language code (for me it's `en`).
5. Inside of the language directory create a file called `commerce.php`.

In `commerce.php` start with something like this:

```php
<?php 
  return [
     'Products' => 'Projects' 
  ];
```

And keep going until you have all the strings you want translated added.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Commerce 3.0 introduces the ability to rename the Product Title and Variant Title when creating a product type.